# PHP: Не выводится через echo значение переменной из массива $_SESSION

Tags: php

По задумке, в следующей форме входа на сайт должно появиться сообщение об ошибке, если капча была введена неверно:

```
<form name="from" method="post" action="signin.php">        
    ...
    <img src="captcha.php" alt="" />
    <input type="text" name="captcha">

    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['error_auth'])){echo $_SESSION['error_auth'];}
    ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Вход" disabled>
</form>
```

Проверка капчи в `signin.php` осуществляется следующим образом:

```
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['generatedCaptcha'] != $inputedCaptcha) {
    $_SESSION['error_auth'] = 'Введённые цифры не соответствуют сгенерированным'; 
    // ... или просто не были введены
    header('Location: http://example.com/singin');
    exit;
}
```

С помощью отладчика я установил, что если капчу не ввести, то в приведённое выше условие мы попадаем и переменная `$_SESSION['error_auth']` успешно инициализируется. Далее, как Вы видите, происходит возврат на страницу входа, где по задумке должно выполниться условие `isset($_SESSION['error_auth'])`.

Тем не менее, по какой-то причине сообщение `$_SESSION['error_auth']` не отображается. В чем причина? По идее, данные сессии не должны теряться при возврате на страницу входа после остановки скрипта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "С помощью отладчика я установил" интересно, а чтож ты не посмотрел
>   что в переменных самих. Пхп такой что 0 == false(True) или 0000 == 0 и
>   кучу подобного. Есть еще === он сравнивает типы и значения. тоесть не
>   сможет получится что 0 === '' неравенство типов. И если сессии не
>   существует там возможно null.

(перечитал понел что со сравнением у вас все оки)

"По идее, данные сессии не должны теряться при возврате на страницу входа после остановки скрипта." Верно, файл сесии пользователя находится на сервере, а у пользователя лишь кука индефикатор. (пока оба живы сессия должна работать).

Когда увидел что вы делаете

```
$_SESSION['error_auth'] = 'Введённые цифры не соответствуют сгенерированным';
```

Не заметил лишь одного

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. `session_start();` у меня есть, просто забыл добавить в код (только что добавил). К сожалению, не понял, какие исправления внести в соответствии с Вашим ответом. `$_SESSION['error_auth']` имеет тип строка, и при вызове `isset($_SESSION['error_auth'])` должно быть возвращено `1`. Это значит, что после завершения `signin.php` условие `if(isset($_SESSION['error_auth']))` должно выполняться. Тем не менее, либо этого не происходит, либо условие выполняется, но присвоенное значение куда-то затерялось.

Comment: когда начинаете работать с сессиями то их откройте. тоесть перед isset должен быть session_start();. еще по желанию их можно закрыть(не уничтожить)

Comment: Отлично, теперь понял! Ещё раз спасибо за ответ!