# Минимально необходимое количество вызовов session_start();

Tags: php

Предположим, мы делаем задачу авторизации на сайте. Используются следующие файлы:

- **index.php** - файл с формой входа
- **captcha.php** - файл с капчей
- **singnin.php** - файл со скриптом отправки.

Экспериментальным путём я установил, что вызов `session_start` требуется в каждом файле:

- Если мы что-то ввели не так, то в сессию записывается сообщение об ошибке и выводится на главной странице (насчёт этого у меня был [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/611028/php-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-echo-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-session/611030?noredirect=1#comment838731_611030))

  ```
  if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){echo $_SESSION['error'];}
  ```
- В `captcha.php` нужно сгенерировать цифры, которые мы опять же записываем в сессию.
- В `signin.php` мы сверяем введённые данные с капчей, т. е. нам нужны данные из сессии.

Учитывая, что все файлы связаны между собой (`captcha.php` выводится через `img` в `index.php`, а `singnin` вызывается из `index.php` через атрибут `action`), чем объясняется необходимость вызова `session_start` в каждом из них?

Answer (score 5):

Для более правильного решения, нужно использовать единую точку входа `index.php`, а все остальное - должно подключаться на `index.php`, через тот-же роутинг и тогда вам не придется постоянно вызывать `session_start()` в каждом файле.
И не нужно в сессии записывать ошибки, - вы отправляете POST, GET, PUT, etc - запросы и должны тут же получать ответ, а не писать в сессию и непонятно куда выводить.

Answer (score 2):

если я правильно понял про "action", то думать что файлы связаны в этом случае не верно.

- юзер запрашивает у веб-сервера главную страницу (index.php)
- веб-сервер передает запрос интерпретатору php
- php запускает index.php который выводит страницу с формой
- php возвращает данные серверу, а сервер клиенту(юзеру)

На этом общение с сервером закончилось. upd:(когда клиент получит страницу, он выполнит еще один запрос на captcha.php загружая картинку)

Когда юзер вбивает капчу, она отправляется по адресу, указанному в

```
<form action="signin.php">
```

Здесь начинается всё с начала, по схеме выше.

Веб-сервер больше не запустит index.php , потому что "параметры запроса" вызвать signin.php
Если там нет session_start() как в index.php, то мы не сможем обратится к переменным сессии.
Собственно вот и всё.

Посмотрите шаблон "единая точка входа" или лучше начните смотреть какой нибудь популярный фреймворк.